# Glossaries - modified page list (back-references)

Tags: glossaries, back-referencing

I want to have a modified page list (back-references) of my glossary, list of acronyms and symbols. With `\glsaddallunused` at the end of the document, I add all entries to the lists. Because of that, it appears that some entries have no page references and some do have (which is exactly what I want). The page list should be:

- if there are no page numbers, no additional text and no brackets should appear.
- if there is a reference to one page only: "(page #)"
- if there are references to more than one page: "(pages #,#-#,...,# and #)"

I achieved a similar behavior in my bibliography (which I do not understand at all) by doing:

```
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    {\footnotesize\mbox{
        \ifcase #1%
            (Not directly cited)%
        \or
            (Cited on page #2)%
        \else
            (#1 cites on pages #2)%
        \fi}
    }
}
```

If this is absolutely not possible with glossaries, I would be happy to have:

- if there are no page numbers, no additional text should appear.
- if there is a reference to one or more pages: "(#)"

MWE that does *not* have a different page list depending on the references:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backref=page,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[footnote,acronym,toc,hyperfirst]{glossaries}

% acronym style (Nicola Talbot)
\newacronymstyle{ex-footnote}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{footnote}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{hyperfirst, footnote}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
}
\setacronymstyle{ex-footnote}


% glossary stile
\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{MyGlossaryStyle}{%
% Use longtable with two columns:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.2\textwidth}p{.755\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
% start of the environment:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\hspace{-6pt}%
  \glstarget{##1}{##2}%
  & ##3\glspostdescription%
  \space\footnotesize\mbox{(##5)}\tabularnewline%
}%
% Blank row between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\\}%
}
\glossarystyle{MyGlossaryStyle}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries


% arconyms
\newacronym{D}{D}{Is not used}
\newacronym{DD}{DD}{\glslink{displacement damage}{Displacement Damage}}
\newacronym{DDD}{DDD}{Displacement Damage Dose}
\newacronym{FPGA}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}

% Gloassaries
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage}{
name = {Displacement Damage},
description = {Displacement damage description}
}
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage dose}{
name = {Displacement Damage Dose},
description = {\Gls{DD} dose description}
}
\newglossaryentry{interconnect}{
name = {Interconnect},
description = {The wiring resources in an \gls{FPGA}}
}


\begin{document}

page 1\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean?

\clearpage
\newpage

page 2\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}, \gls{displacement damage dose} and again \gls{DDD}.\\

\clearpage
\newpage

page 3\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}

\clearpage
\newpage
page 4
\clearpage
\newpage

page 5\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=main, title=Glossary]

\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

**Note 1:** Since there are cross-references in the MWE, you have to compile with makeglossaries twice, e.g.:

```
- pdflatex
- makeglossaries
- pdflatex
- makeglossaries
- pdflatex
```

**Note 2:** A problem in the page list occurs, one comma and space is added falsely, see below:

[image]

**Note 3:** The 5th argument in `\glossaryentryfield` is the page list. It does neither work to check if the list is empty with

```
\ifx##5\relax
```

nor

```
\if\relax\detokenize{##5}\relax
```

nor

```
\ifthenelse{\isempty{##5}}
```

**Note 4:** I don't mind to clean up the code of my glossary style =)

Comment: Does anybody know where to find a detailed documentation for `\glossaryentryfield` and how to check if the 5th parameter is empty?

Comment: I would appreciate any help, even if it is not the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem.

I had a look at the output of `\detokenize{##2}` (where `##2`is the page list in `\glossentry`) and found that it has a substring `glsignore` if there is no page number. Furthermore there is at least one substring `delimR`or `delimN`between page numbers (only when here is more than one page referenced).

Since `\glossaryentryfield` is deprecated, you should use `\glossentry` instead.

You are welcome to post a more elegant solution ...

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[backref=page,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[footnote,acronym,toc,hyperfirst]{glossaries}

% acronym style (Nicola Talbot)
\newacronymstyle{ex-footnote}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{footnote}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{hyperfirst, footnote}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
    \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
}
\setacronymstyle{ex-footnote}


% glossary style
\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{MyGlossaryStyle}{%
% Use longtable with two columns:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.2\textwidth}p{.755\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
% start of the environment:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}% Name
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##2}}{glsignore}{%
      \footnotesize\space (Not used)%
    }{%
      \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##2}}{delim}{%
        \footnotesize\space (Pages ##2)%
      }{%
        \footnotesize\space (Page ##2)%
      }%
    }%
    \tabularnewline% end of row
  }%
% Similarly for sub-entries
  \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}% Name
    & \glossentrydesc{##2}% Description
    \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##3}}{glsignore}{%
      \footnotesize\space (Not used)%
    }{%
      \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##3}}{delim}{%
        \footnotesize\space (Pages ##3)%
      }{%
        \footnotesize\space (Page ##3)%
      }%
    }%
    \tabularnewline% end of row
  }%
% Blank row between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\\}%
}
\setglossarystyle{MyGlossaryStyle}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries


% arconyms
\newacronym{D}{D}{Is not used}
\newacronym{DD}{DD}{\glslink{displacement damage}{Displacement Damage}}
\newacronym{DDD}{DDD}{Displacement Damage Dose}
\newacronym{FPGA}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}

% Gloassaries
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage}{
name = {Displacement Damage},
description = {Displacement damage description}
}
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage dose}{
name = {Displacement Damage Dose},
description = {\Gls{DD} dose description}
}
\newglossaryentry{interconnect}{
name = {Interconnect},
description = {The wiring resources in an \gls{FPGA}}
}


\begin{document}

page 1\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean?

\clearpage
\newpage

page 2\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}, \gls{displacement damage dose} and again \gls{DDD}.\\

\clearpage
\newpage

page 3\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}, \gls{displacement damage dose}

\clearpage
\newpage
page 4
\clearpage
\newpage

page 5\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean again?\\
\Gls{DDD}


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=main, title=Glossary]

\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit 1**

I added `\gls{displacement damage dose}` on page 3. That is why page 3 is also added to the glossary in comparison to the original MWE in the question.