# glossaries-extra pre-location tag not shown in specific conditions

Tags: glossaries-extra

I'm having a problem that the glossary-extra pre-location tag (e.g., "Pages:" before the page list) is not shown in certain specific conditions.

As far as I can tell, these conditions seem to be:

- Using `\glsresetall` before each `\chapter{}` (e.g., to force full form acronyms on first use in chapter)
- No use of `\gls{}` in the chapter(s) before the glossary
- `\glsaddallunused` before `\printglossary` so all glossary entries are shown

One solution is to not issue `\glsresetall` whenever `\gls{}` is not used in a chapter, but this is not very practical.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what a better solution may be?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }
\makeglossaries
\newacronym[description={Description.}]{MWE}{MWE}{minimum working example}

\begin{document}

\glsresetall
\chapter{First chapter}
\gls{MWE}
\glsresetall
\chapter{Last chapter}
% (no \gls{} used)
\glsaddallunused
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I _think_ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256152/glossaries-modified-page-list-back-references is related, at least the problem/symptoms (not sure if the solution there is also applicable).